# Adding two dataframes without trucating values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames like this

```
data_1 = {
    "price": [1]*8
}

data_2 = {
    "price": [3, 3, 3],
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data_1, index=pd.date_range('2021/01/01', '2021/01/08', periods=8))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data_2, index=pd.date_range('2021/01/03', '2021/01/05', periods=3))
```

But when I add them together, I get the following, but the problem is it replaces 1 with NaN

```
df3 = df1['price'] + df2['price']
>>>
2021-01-01    NaN
2021-01-02    NaN
2021-01-03    4.0
2021-01-04    4.0
2021-01-05    4.0
2021-01-06    NaN
2021-01-07    NaN
2021-01-08    NaN
```

What I want is this

```
2021-01-01    1
2021-01-02    1
2021-01-03    4.0
2021-01-04    4.0
2021-01-05    4.0
2021-01-06    1
2021-01-07    1
2021-01-08    1
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.add` instead for the dataframes:

```
df = df1.add(df2, fill_value=0)
```

result:

```
2021-01-01    1.0
2021-01-02    1.0
2021-01-03    4.0
2021-01-04    4.0
2021-01-05    4.0
2021-01-06    1.0
2021-01-07    1.0
2021-01-08    1.0
Name: price, dtype: float64
```

This will cause issues for dfs with additional columns, so take care.  See @jezrael answer for a series specific (more robust) solution

Comment: @jezrael not copied.  I did notice I came up with the same answer after finding an issue with my original.  In any case it's not (quite?) the same now and gave you credit

Comment: Thanks a lot anan01, how stupid of me, I though fill_value would fill it with zeroes instead of the original values.

Comment: @jezrael well yes.  I was writing my own before I saw yours... I don't think that's too hard to imagine.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.add.html) method with `fill_value=0`:

```
df3 = df1['price'].add(df2['price'], fill_value=0).astype(int)
print (df3)
2021-01-01    1
2021-01-02    1
2021-01-03    4
2021-01-04    4
2021-01-05    4
2021-01-06    1
2021-01-07    1
2021-01-08    1
Name: price, dtype: int32
```

Comment: Thanks a lot jezrael, but if it is not much work, why do you have to call the astype method.

Comment: @SAK - It is not encessary, only if all data are floats with `.0` then is possible use it.

Comment: @jezrael upvote to clear  the air?  I have learned a lot from your answers to other questions and appreciate your contributions :)

Comment: @anon01 - Good luck, happy coding!